# PhoneGap with Asp.net MVC 4? - Anyone know what Steve Sanderson was getting at?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile, cordova, razor

I watched  [Single Page Application Presentation](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/03/06/single-page-application-packages-and-samples/)  and in the 4:15 mark of the video he mentions deploying his single page application to an "app store" by using phonegap.

Does anyone actually know how he was planning to do this(he never actually goes into it how to do it in the presentation).

From my understanding is that no mobile device supports asp.net mvc and phonegap only supports html/javascript/css.

I see he is using razor so the only thing I can think that he writes the code in mvc and then somehow takes a tool that quickly goes through the application and renders all the views just into plain html.

Then since he is using this new webapi(how I understand it is basically a webserver that just does restful data).

So then he would build the application as plain html and package it with phonegap and each of the link are pointing to the webapi and as long as that is hosted the application would work.

Does anyone have any other ideas on what he meant?

Comment: They no longer going to release single page applications for mvc 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a single page app, there is only one view. So once you open it in a browser, you'd have everything you need. Chrome has a "Save Page As..., Webpage Complete" feature that saves the page and all resources to a single directory (other browsers have something similar). So that would be an easy way to do it.

Also, if you wanted to script it, you could used a headless browser to achieve the same effect.

Comment: so if your using a regular asp.net mvc application then webpage complete? So basically you agree with me that is what he is most likely doing though webapi + saved html pages + phongap.